# Weights with plm package

Tags: r, linear-regression, panel-data, plm

My data frame looks like something as follows:

```
unique.groups<- letters[1:5]
unique_timez<- 1:20
groups<- rep(unique.groups, each=20)
my.times<-rep(unique_timez, 5)

play.data<- data.frame(groups, my.times, y= rnorm(100), x=rnorm(100), POP= 1:100)
```

I would like to run the following weighted regression:

```
plm(y~x + factor(my.times) , 
data=play.data, 
index=c('groups','my.times'), model='within', weights= POP)
```

But I do not believe the plm package allows for weights. The answer I'm looking for the coefficient from the model below:

```
fit.regular<- lm(y~x + factor(my.times) + factor(my.groups),
weights= POP, data= play.data)
desired.answer<- coefficients(fit.regular)
```

However, I am looking for an answer with the plm package because it is much faster to get the coefficient of the within estimator with plm with larger datasets and many groups.

Comment: The development version of `plm` now features a `weights` argument for `plm()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**: This problem does not exist anymore since plm features a weight function now (see @Helix123 comment above).

Even though I know of no solution with the `plm` package, the `felm`function in the [`lfe`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lfe/) package handles weights correctly in the context of fixed effects (which seems what you need from the syntax of your example code). It is particularly written with a focus on speed in the presence of many observations and groups.

The `lfe` package focuses on fixed effects only, so if you need random effects the `lme4` package might [be more suited](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/168920/is-the-weights-option-in-lmer-doing-what-i-want) to your needs.

Comment: The `plm()` `weights` option seems to be bugged, though.

Comment: @randy Could you please be more specific? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am looking for exactly this information. I found this answer http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Longitudinal-Weights-in-PLM-package-td3298823.html by one of the author of the packages, which seems to suggest there is no way of using weights directly within the plm package.